# Mapping and conservation law

Tags: euclidean-geometry, transformation

What is a general map from a point sitting in one dimensional space, to a set of points sitting in two dimensional space, to a set of points sitting in three dimensional space, to a set of points embedded in a torus sitting in four dimensional space? This is what I have but I'm not sure if it's correct notation. The parentheses are to show that those mappings inside the parentheses occur before the mapping to the torus.

The motivation for this comes from physics and viewing these points as fixed points in space throughout all transformations, which lends itself to a conservation of momentum law for these points, which can be thought of as particles. The last embedding onto the torus is to provide a ring structure to the solution space. Physicists are not necessarily known as tidy mathematicians so I thought I'd seek help from the pros.

$ F : ((\Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2) \to \Bbb R^3) \hookrightarrow \Bbb T^4 $.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it an embedding? If so, how can "one point sitting in one dimensional space" map to "a set of points sitting in two dimensional space"?

Comment: The last transformation is an embedding, the first three are supposed to be structure preserving maps, so maybe I could just get rid of the $ \Bbb R $ and start from $\Bbb R^2$

Comment: So, $\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb T^4$ is en embedding. Such are often written using `\hookrightarrow`, a combination of an arrow and the subset symbol: $\mathbb R^3 \hookrightarrow \mathbb T^4.$

Comment: ah thank you @md2perpe I will edit the question to reflect that

Comment: Do you have names/symbols (like $f$) for the first two mappings?

Comment: yes I have those

Comment: Could you please give me the names for the mappings (also for the embedding if that also has one)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81243/discussion-between-george-thomas-and-md2perpe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more brackets to make the notation unambiguous. Suppose we write something like

$F: \big ( (\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2) \to \mathbb R^3\big) \to \mathbb T^4 $.

That could be reasonably interpreted to mean $F$ takes as input a function $f:(\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2) \to \mathbb R^3 $ and each $F(f)$ is an element of $\mathbb  T^4$. But what does $f:(\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2) \to \mathbb R^3 $ mean? It means $f$ takes as input a function $\alpha: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$ and each $f(\alpha)$ is an element of $\mathbb R^3$.

**Exercise**: What does $G: \big ( \mathbb R \to (\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3) \big) \to \mathbb T^4 $ mean?

A slightly more common notation would be to write something like $\hom(X,Y)$, or $\text{Mor} (X,Y)$ or $\text{fun}(X,Y)$ or $F(X,Y)$ for the set of all maps from $X$ to $Y$, or $C(X,Y)$ for the set of all continuous maps. In that case the above example is written:

$F \in C \, (C \,(C\,(\mathbb R, \mathbb R^2)\,, \mathbb R^3)\,, \mathbb T^4)$.

Personally I'd stick to the earlier notation. It is easier on the eyes and also resembles function definition syntax from some programming languages.

Comment: ah i see, thank  you

Comment: Is this really what you want, @GeorgeThomas? Do you want a function taking a function? I interpret your question as asking for a chain of mappings, one from 1D to 2D, then one from 2D to 3D, and then finally one from 3D to the 4D torus: $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb T^4.$

Comment: Hmm, yes it is a chain of mappings... I guess I need the actual functions to act as transformations to go from one mapping to the next, right?

Comment: It's hard deriving those

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you have first a mapping $\mathbb R \stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow} \mathscr P(\mathbb R^2),$ where $\mathscr P$ denotes power set, and then a chain of mappings 
$\mathbb R^2 \stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb R^3 \stackrel{\iota} {\hookrightarrow} \mathbb T^4$ acting on each element in $f(t)$ for $t \in \mathbb R.$